# Voltage regulation: are the ground diodes necessary? (Picture added)

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

Are the diodes on the ground line necessary?

[image: schematics]

Would the following work to provide the device with 12v and 4A?

[image: schematics 2]

Comment: Where did you find this circuit? It doesn't make any sense without context (and it might not make sense even with context). What is connected to each side?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to accomplish. Certainly, putting two 12V zener diodes in series with an 18V power source will prevent any power from reaching whatever's on the right.

Comment: 18v 3a power supply but I need 12v 4a for my device

Comment: You can't get 4 A from a 3 A power supply unless you use a switching PSU.

Comment: You need a DC/DC converter as you can not get 4A out of a 3A device without conversion. You also need better then 88% efficiency.

Comment: ok, say I use an 18v 4a supply instead, will the diodes on the ground line be necessary or should I remove them?

Comment: Why do you think you need them?

Comment: Forget about this circuit, with or without ground diodes. Get a 12V 4A supply or get a 18V 4A supply and add a standard regulator.

Comment: I added a new picture to the post, would that work?

Comment: This is not how you use a zener diode.

Comment: Some thought provoking questions regarding your update: (1) If you put a 12 V Zener diode in series with an 18 V supply how many volts will be left at your load? (2) If you put a 3 Ω resistor in series with your load and you were able to pull 4 A through it how many volts would you lose across your resistor?

Comment: Hearth, can you provide a link that shows the proper way to use a zener diode?

Comment: Transistor, (1) i thought it would be 12v as per what ive read, (2) 3ohm to limit it to 4A if a higher amp supply is used. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Zeners are used to shunt excess voltage to ground for regulation. In series it is a bit odd unless you only want your device to turn on above a certain voltage level, but even then, there are far better ways to do that task.

Comment: Jarrod, i dont want to ground anything as that will waste wattage (i am trying to minimise wastage) and yes if any less than 12v is supplied then the device should not be powered. Can you please outline or share a link as to a "far better way to do that"?

Comment: *" as that will waste wattage"* If you go from 18V to 12V (dropping 6 volts) **not** using a DC/DC converter, you always loss wattage. If you use a 6V zener it will burn 6x3A is 18W. The zener does NOT save you power.

Comment: fair point, i will scrap this schematic

Comment: Please read [this link](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode_7.html). Your current schematic simply will not do what you think it will.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will read and then re-evaluate every decision I made to get to this schematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUhLSI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A Zener dropper circuit.*

If you really wanted to use a Zener diode you would just use a 6 V one and drop the voltage as shown in Figure 1. Since you mention 4 A current the power dissipated in the Zener would be calculated by \$ P = V_ZI = 6 \times 4 = 24 \ \text W \$ but you won't find a device with this power rating - not easily at least.

Your scheme had several problems.

1. You were dropping 12 V across the Zener leaving you with a maximum of 6 at your load.
2. You have a series resistor of 3 Ω which, with your remaining 6 V supply, limits the maximum current to \$ I = \frac {V}{R} = \frac {6}{3} = 2 \ \text A \$ into a short circuit. If you have any kind of a load with a resistance of more than 0 Ω you'll get less than 2 A.
3. In your original post you were hoping to draw 4 A from the 12 V side while supply the circuit with a 3 A supply. This wouldn't end well.

The solutions, as discussed in the comments are:

1. Purchase the correct 12 V, 4 A supply in the first place.
2. Use a DC/DC converter / buck converter or switching regulator to step the voltage down. For 12 V at 4 A you will need a 48 W converter. The power into the converter will be \$ P_{in} = \frac {P_{out}}{Eff} \$.

Comment: Thank you for such a well written answer, it explains a lot.